# Unique MAC address in L3 switch

Tags: dell

Dell 6224 is L3 switch: Does L3 switch have unique MAC address for different port?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, it's unthinkable for an Ethernet port not to have an individual MAC address. For a lot of reasons... LAN communication, port-channel, etc. But let's doubt it, in the world of machines everything is possible! You could check that, you have a bunch of **show** commands there:

**show interfaces detail** {**ethernet** interface | **port-channel** port-channel-number}, where

```
• interface — A valid Ethernet port. 
• port-channel-number — A valid port-channel trunk index.
```

Even **show bridge address-table** [**vlan** vlan ] [**ethernet** interface | **port-channel** port-channel-number ] could help.

In the end, the output of the **show tech-support** command combines the output of a lot of other  commands. Of course, it's verbose and you have to scroll it, but you need that MAC! :)